# msSaveBlob, msSaveOrOpenBlob fail when IE Enhanced Security Configuration is on

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

When trying to get a file to download in IE 11 through javascript using msSaveBlob and msSaveOrOpenBlob I get an error message stating that the file couldn't be downloaded.
Ive tried adding the site to Trusted sites but this does not fix the problem.
Turning off IE Enhanced Security Configuration in Server Manager however does seem to fix the issue and files download successfully.

Is there any way to download files using msSaveBlob or msSaveOrOpenBlob while keeping IE Enhanced Security Configuration on?

IE version: 11

OS: Windows 2012 R2, Windows 2016

Sample code used for testing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh779016(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved by lowering the security level of the Internet zone or choosing a custom security for the Internet zone and allowing downloads.

It appears that IE 11 treats blobs as being under the internet zone, even when the site itself has been added to trusted sites, so changing the security level of the Trusted zone won't work, it has to be the Internet zone.